# Can Pfx polymerase add only one 3' A overhang?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, dna-sequencing, cloning

I am trying to clone a PCR product that was amplified using Pfx polymerase into pGemT vector. I had to A-tail the PCR product using Taq polymerase since Pfx only generates blunt end products. My ligation reaction was successful, however when I got the sequences, there is an extra T between the 3'end-T of pGem and the start codon of my product. It only happens in the 3' end of pGemT (or 5' end of my product). Can Pfx polymerase generates PCR products with just one 3'end overhang? or Can Taq polymerase add two consecutive dATP during the A-tailing?

Please write me your thoughts ASAP, it has happened twice and it's a pain already :(

GGC CGC GGG A-**T-T**-*T*-G ATG GGA AGC ATG AAG

The two Ts in Bold belong to pGemT, the T Italic is the extra T I've got from the sequencing reaction. After the T in Italic you may find the 5'end of my insert. The second T (in bold) from pGemT is the one that ligates with the overhang A added through the A-tailing protocol.

Comment: Pfx wont add an overhang. Check [this](http://www.invitrogen.com/1/3/pfx-polymerase). Taq generally adds one A

Comment: Could you post sequences at the two junctions, just to make the problem absolutely clear?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! I have included above the sequences at the two junctions as you requested. Hope this helps to better understand the issue.

Comment: did you check the electrophretogram of your sequencing reaction. just to make sure that it is not an erroneous base call

Comment: Yes, I've checked every peak of the electropherograms and there is clearly an extra T there. From four clones I've sent for sequencing, all of them had this extra T. I have called promega to confirm it is not a vector issue. They said it is possible that they may have produced a wrong batch of pGemT with an extra T. I can't believe that was the case though. Anyways they will possibly send me a new batch next week. If you think that might be a vector issue, please let me know.

Comment: Just try with TOPO-TA once.. if you have it in your lab..

Comment: Ok, I am wondering if I can amplify the insert from the clone I already have into pGemT? As the coding region of my gene is fine and primers will unlikely pick that extra T, I would like to use the pGemT construct to amplify my gene, because I've ran out of PCR product.

Comment: Yeah, as far as the experiment is concerned you dont have any problem. Even with an extra T there is no problem with the current construct wrt expression. You can amplify the clone too if you want. And, it is always better if you keep some sequences ahead of start codon (such as kozak consensus sequences or restriction sites etc).

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bad batch of pGemT, as I think these vectors are generated by restriction digestion. Also, the suggestion of using TOPO-TA would be quite expensive if you do not already have it (and I suspect that s/he doesn't by the use of pGemT). Sometimes erroneous bases get added by Taq. As @WYSIWYG has said, the insertion of this extra base does not change your reading frame and won't affect expression. If you were really concerned, the easiest method is to do a simple mutagenesis, but I don't see a need for it since you will move the insert to a destination vector.

Comment: I understand the extra T won't change the reading frame of the coding region. However, I am planning to subclone this insert into pet30 expression vector. For this step, I need to digest pGemT-insert leaving the extra T in the digested fragment that is to be subcloned. When this happens, the coding region of my protein will not be in frame. Therefore, I will get another protein completely different as the reading frame will be shifted. My question is: if I use pGemT-insert as a template for another PCR, is there any chance to pick that extra T? Forward primer starts from GATG..

Comment: I am asking to run another PCR using the wrong construct (with the extra T) as a template because my gene is lowly expressed. I had to struggle a lot in order to get the coding region amplified without mutations. So, running another PCR using cDNA as a template will be a pain. Now that I have the coding region healthy into pGemT with an extra T upstream my gene, can I use it for PCR?